# How to debug c++ code wrapped with cython in a multiprocessing python program?

Tags: python, c++, debugging

I wrote some c++ codes and wrapped them with cython, and used them in a multiprocessing python program. Now the code works well on linux but would be stuck on windows. Are there any suggestions to debug this?

After the program stuck, I `ctrl+c` my program, log for exiting the processing using c++ and cython code would not appear, so I'm sure the processing using c++ have been crashed, which leads to stuck. Now I want to know where it crashed. I know every processing's pid.

Comment: Visual Studio has the option to attach the debugger to a process. Hence, you can debug this process even if it hasn't been started out of Visual Studio. In the past, I used WinDbg for this but this is decades ago. I don't know whether it's still available but for Visual Studio, there is a community edition which can be used free of charge.

Comment: It seems WinDbg is still available: [Install the Windows debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/) ;-)